# Python question to calculate fee after 10 years

Tags: python, loops

I am learning python and I am trying to solve the problem below
*"Suppose that the tuition for a university is $10,000 this year and increases 5% every year. In one year, the tuition will be $10,500. Write a program that displays the tuition in 10 years and the total cost of 4 years’ worth of tuition starting after the 10th year."*

The program calculates well the value of th fee upto the 10th year but I dont know what I am doing wrong thereafter when it tries to claculate fee for the 4 years after the 10th year
The code I have come up with is

```
tuition=10000
yearlyIncreasePercentage =0.05
tuitionInTenYears=0
fourYearsOfTuition =0
year=0
while (year<15):
    year=year+1
    tuition=tuition*1.05

    if (year==10):
        tuitionInTenYears=tuition
print("Tuition in ten years is ",tuitionInTenYears)

for year in range(10,14,1):
    tuition+=tuition

print("The four-year total tuition in ten years is ",tuition)
```

Comment: sum(tuition[9:14])

Comment: @BHC - I think you mean `sum(tuition[11:15])`?

Comment: What is total cost of 4 years’ worth of tuition starting after the 10th year? Can you please give an example calculation and the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to increase the amount 5% every year. 
 Try below code:

```
import math

final = 0
for i in range(10,14):
     final += (10000*pow(1.05,i))

print(final)
```

Comment: A little math will show that there is no need for a `for` loop, this is the compound interest and it can be calculated in O(1) with a specific formula https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php

Comment: Well described @ChatterOne